# How to resolve VS Load and Webtest ASP Forms User Login Response URL Validation not equal to response URL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, load, performance-testing, web-testing

How to resolve VS Load and Webtest ASP Forms Auth User Login Response URL Validation value of the ExpectedResponseUrl property "Login" does not equal the actual response URL QueryString parameters were ignored. Webtest and load test fails.

Comment: could you add code generating this exception?

Comment: Can you provide email to send you code.

Comment: ????? I will not solve your issue, but other SO user could help you if you will show your problem

Comment: It using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx to generate Login id's.

Comment: So generated code is larger than they amount of characters allowd by Add Comment text box.

Comment: (1) [edit] you question to add details, do not try an put them into a comment. (2) Microsoft provide lots of help pages about how to debug web tests.